# pandas dataframe converting complex date-format to date dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm

Tags: pandas, dataframe, date-conversion, string-to-datetime

I'm using python and pandas to transform csv's, 
I imported the csv as a dataframe.

the dataframe has a string-column containing dates in format "January 1, 2016, Hour 0"

I'd like to convert that string into a date or even string in format dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm

note that in this case the minutes will always be 0.

thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done it using datetime and strptime as following

```
df['field'].apply(lambda x : datetime.strptime(x, '%B %d, %Y, Hour %H').strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:00'))
```

or generally:

```
df['field'].apply(lambda x : datetime.strptime(x, old_formatted_date).strftime(new_formatted_date))
```

for more on datetime default lib check:
[datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)

and datetime format codes:
[datetime format codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)